# NSDate object shows wrong time

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to create the NSDate object with date "1 oct 2013 8:00:00". I used the following code

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setYear:2013];
[components setMonth:10];
[components setDay:1];
[components setHour: 8];
[components setMinute: 00];
[components setSecond: 00];
NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

> But when i print the date it gives wrong time "2013-10-01 02:30:00 +0000"

Comment: How many times does this question come up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because of time zone: you are in the Indian Standard Time (IST) zone, which lags 5 hours and 30 minutes behind GMT. When you set `NSDate` to `8:00` from the components, it uses your time zone, so the result gets adjusted to `02:30` so that `NSDate` has the correct GMT time. If you would like to set the time to `08:00` GMT, set your components' `timeZone` to GMT:

```
[components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```